# Doing BNF for a simplified SQL “where” clause

Tags: sql, parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, bnf

I have the following SQL statement with a rudimentary BNF applied:

```
SELECT
    from_expression [, from_expression] ...
FROM
    from_source
WHERE
    condition


from_source:
    table_name

from_expression:
    literal              # 'abc', 1, 
    column               # Table.Field1, Table.Profit
    function             # ABS(...)
    operator invocation  # NOT field1, 2+3, Genres[0], Genres[1:2], Address.name

condition:
    ???
```

For now the `WHERE` condition is the same as the `from_expression` but evaluated as a boolean. What would be the proper way to show that?

Comment: Probably start with parenthesis, conjunctions, disjunctions, then the supported types of conditionals (which might have restricted operand productions in this simplified grammar). Unlike other languages, literals are not valid expressions for conditions. There is nothing necessarily to indicate “evaluated as a boolean” in the grammar.

Comment: That is a condensed extract might look like: `cond_or: cond or cond, cond: expr = expr | expr < expr | expr is null, expr: literal | identifier` etc. The expr doesn’t feed back into cond directly.

Comment: @user2864740 wouldn't all those evaluate to a vaid `from_expression` as well? For example, `select 1 or 2, 1 and 2, 1 is null, 1 < 1, 1` is valid SQL.

Comment: @David542 I wrote the LiveSQL module of an ORM, that allows the developer to assemble generic select statements on the fly. As a general rule, SQL expressions can be divided into 6 typed expressions, depending on their result type (numeric, string, time, boolean, binary, etc.). Your "from-expression" can be of any of the six typed expressions, while your "condition" can only be a boolean expression (aka "predicate").

Comment: @TheImpaler right but doesn't the db evaluate whatever it is, so all those types 'work' so to speak: `select * from (select 1 as c) x where 'asdf' and 1 and true and binary '1' and date '2014-01-01' and time '01:02:03'`

Comment: `.. and 1 and ..` is not valid SQL. It will raise a parse-time error in SQL Server. The conditions (or predicates) are very limited when compared to other (GP) languages. See http://sqlfiddle.com for a quick way to verify this is invalid in SQL Server: `select 2 as x where 1` (one would have to consult the SQL standard grammar to argue further about the behavior).

Comment: @David542 Some engines like MySQL are more permissives and they not only accept boolean expressions but also numeric ones in the condition; I believe that any result different from zero is interpreted as true. However, I would consider this an exception to the rule, and it's probably safer to conform to the norm and only consider boolean expressions for the filtering predicate.

Comment: @TheImpaler I see, does the answer I've given make sense for more strict implementations?

Comment: @David542 Yes, I think that option is more accurate. There are many more combinations than the ones you are including in the brief answer, but in my opinion that's the gist of it.

Comment: @TheImpaler cool thanks for the feedback. A couple questions: can you send a link to the LiveSQL ORM, or is that closed-source? And, what would be an example of something I'm missing in the `condition` section?

Comment: @TheImpaler any suggestions on the above two?

Comment: @David542 I hope my explanation helps you in the right direction. Wrtiting that was really exiting to me, and I learned a ton of SQL quirks in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar doesn't care about semantics.

Syntactically, an expression is an expression, nothing more. If you later do some kind of semantic analysis, that is when you'll need to deal with the difference. You might do that in the reduction actions for `condition` and `from_expression`  but it would be cleaner to just build an AST while parsing and do the semantic analysis later on the tree.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be as follow, with examples in-line:

```
expression:
    literal                                       # 'abc', 1, 
    column                                        # Table.Field1, Table.Profit
    function call                                 # ABS(...)
    operator invocation                           # NOT field1, 2+3, Genres[0], Genres[1:2], Address.name

condition:
    expression { = | != | < | <= | > | >= | IN } expression  # Revenue > 0
    expression IS [NOT] NULL                       # Revenue IS NOT NULL
    condition { AND | OR } condition               # Revenue > 0 AND Profit < 100
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment that doesn't fit in the comments section.

I was hesitant to provide the link to the LiveSQL implementation, since it's specifically for Java language, it's open source, but we have never added any documentation whatsoever. Read at your own risk.

The main class is [LiveSQL.java](https://sourceforge.net/p/hotrod/hotrod/ci/maven/tree/hotrod-project/hotrod-livesql/src/main/java/org/hotrod/runtime/livesql/LiveSQL.java): in line 113 you can see the main variant of the select clause. It has many variants, but this is the one that allows the developer to include as many result set columns (expressions) as needed:

```
  public SelectColumnsPhase<Map<String, Object>> select(
      final ResultSetColumn... resultSetColumns) {
    return new SelectColumnsPhase<Map<String, Object>>(this.sqlDialect,
        this.sqlSession, this.liveSQLMapper, false,
        resultSetColumns);
  }
```

Of course, the SELECT clause has many other variants, that you can find in the same class if you explore it a bit. I think I was pretty exhaustive when I researched all variants. It should be [mostly] complete, except for non-standard SQL dialect variations that I didn't consider.

If you follow the QueryBuilder up the WHERE phase you can see how the predicate is assembled in the method `where(final Predicate predicate)` (line 101) of the [SelectFrom.java](https://sourceforge.net/p/hotrod/hotrod/ci/maven/tree/hotrod-project/hotrod-livesql/src/main/java/org/hotrod/runtime/livesql/queries/select/SelectFromPhase.java) class, as in:

```
public SelectWherePhase<R> where(final Predicate predicate) {
  return new SelectWherePhase<R>(this.select, predicate);
}
```

As you can see the WHERE clause does not accept any type of expression. First of all, it only accepts a single expression, not a list. Second this expression must be a Predicate (boolean expression). Of course, this predicate can be as complex as you want, mixing all kinds of expressions and boolean logic. You can peek at the [Predicate.java](https://sourceforge.net/p/hotrod/hotrod/ci/maven/tree/hotrod-project/hotrod-livesql/src/main/java/org/hotrod/runtime/livesql/expressions/predicates/Predicate.java) class to explore all the expressions that can be built.

**Condition**

Let's take as an example the Predicate class described above. If `p` and `q` are boolean expressions and `a`, `b`, `c` are of [mostly] any type you can express the condition as:

```
condition:
  <predicate>

predicate:
  p and q,
  p or q,
  not p,
  ( p ),
  a == b,
  a <> b,
  a > b,
  a < b,
  a >= b,
  a <= b,
  a between b and c,
  a not between b and c,
  a in (b, c, ... )
  a not in (b, c, ... )
```

Of course there are more operators but this gives you the gist of it.